# Appending one-character String to StringBuilder

Tags: java, string, performance

I was wondering if there are some advantages of doing

```
sb.append('\n').toString();
```

over:

```
sb.append("\n").toString();
```

`"\n"` instead of `'\n'` in terms of performance.

Will the version with character instead of string will be more efficient in terms of memory or will compiler figure out that the string is actual a character?

Comment: Why don't you look at the source code of the two `append` methods to see what happens?

Comment: What version of JDK are you using?

Comment: He's asking about wether jvm or javac will optimize one char strings, not what StringBuilder does wether it receives strings or chars.

Comment: Why do you even bother? What's the problem behind that?

Comment: @DanielFigueroa exactly this.

Comment: @Thomas Problem that I discuss with other programmer in the team. I am just eager to know. That's all.

Comment: @PiotrekHryciuk in theory the only valid answer is that it depends (on your compiler, jdk version etc.). On openjdk v8, the char version is probably faster. You can always test it with jmh

Comment: If you have a look at the source code of `append(String)` you'll notice that it'll do much more that what `append(char)` does so you could say that the former _theoretically_ yields lower performance - _practically_ it's probably not very relevant and thus developer/maintainance performance might be more important. I also doubt that the compiler would "optimize" a 1-char string into a char and call another method since the compiler doesn't know whether that's safe to do or not (the logic might be completely different) - in fact you're using a different type explicitly.

Comment: You should compile the `append("\n")` version to see whether the compiler rewrote the code to use a char (which would be faster). Then disassemble with the JDK tool **javap**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a small experiment to test the performance of the two options:

It seems that '\n' is definitely faster on a large scale manipulation.

But hardly noticeable in a smaller scale. Even the memory consumption seems to be very trivial.

This code appends \n , 1000 times:

```
    package test;           
                
                
    public class StringAppend {         
                
        public static void main(String[] args) {            
                
            //Run 1         
            long startTime = System.nanoTime();         
            long startMem = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();          
            StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder("This is a test");            
            for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {           
                sb1.append("\n");           
            }           
            sb1.append("To Test \"\\n\"");          
        System.out.println("sb1 = " + sb1.toString());          
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();           
        long endMem = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();            
            
        //Run 2         
        long startTime2 = System.nanoTime();            
        long startMem2 = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();         
        StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder("This is a test");            
        for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {           
            sb1.append('\n');           
        }           
        sb1.append("To Test '\\n'");            
        long endTime2 = System.nanoTime();          
        long endMem2 = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();           
        System.out.println("Run1: append \"\\n\"execution time [" + (endTime - startTime) + " nanos], Memory " + "[" + (endMem - startMem) + "]");          
        System.out.println("Run2: append '\\n' execution time [" + (endTime2 - startTime2) + " nanos], Memory " + "[" + (endMem2 - startMem2) + "]");           
    }           
}
```

Below is the result that I noticed on a high performance laptop:

> Run1: append "\n"execution time [767526 nanos], Memory [0]
>
> Run2: append '\n' execution time [121823 nanos], Memory [0]

Answer (score 1):

In class `java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder`, appending a single `char` will ensure/expand capacity by `1`, while appending a `CharSequence` or `String` will do the same with the object's length.

Arguably there would be a slight overhead as `length` is invoked in the later cases.

You're hardly ever going to notice it though.

One may also argue that appending a `String` literal has the overhead of interning the literal, but again, that should be considered as minimal overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Java does create an instance of a string even for a single character string.

```
java.lang.String:

public class Test{
    public static void main(final String[] args){
        System.out.println("c".getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: By "single character" he means `'\n'`. Note the `'` instead of `"`. Characters bounded by `'` are of the primitive type `char`.